# How do I repair a leak in my roof?

Tags: repair, ceiling, roofing

I'm dealing with a water leak issue after the recent ice storm. Noticed dripping around my sliding door jam and the crease where the ceiling meets the wall. I've cut a 4” square hole to drain water, but I can't access it through the attic crawl space due to fear of falling through the ceiling. I suspect it's from an ice dam on the roof.

Any advice on immediate steps and what type of professional handles repairs?

Comment: A roofer will be the best, a general contractor will also work.  Leaks need to be fix where the water is coming from, not from where they show in the inside.  The attic will only point where the leak is, but needs fixing from on top/outside.

Comment: That looks like an Answer, @crip659. (I have a roofer starting work tomorrow redoing some flashing, replacing most of the fascia boards, and putting up new and better-designed gutters; if I'm lucky that will solve my leak. If not we'll have to do exploratory surgery to try to find the actual path of water flow.)

Comment: @keshlam   Finding the actual leak is the biggest problem with roof leaks, since water will travel before dripping down.

Comment: For what it's worth, the leak I'm now having repaired turned out to be rotted siding on a gable-end wall. Putting up fresh cedar shakes on that one area is setting me back about $20k; cedar is durable (the stuff being removed is probably 100 years old) but not cheap. While I've got the guys on site I'm throwing another $15k into replacing soffit boards and gutters which also need work.

Comment: "A boat is a hole in the water that you throw money into. A swimming pool is a hole in the ground that you throw money into. A house is a hole in the air that you throw money into."

Answer (score 3):

Sounds exactly like an ice dam.

Ice dams happen when the roof is warmed by the house, snow melts and seeps between the shingles, the re-freezes and expands, creating a water path.

The first thing you need to do is to stop the dam. If you have the means (eg a roof rake), remove all of the snow from the roof. The snow is the source of new water.

A roofer should be able to remove the ice dam -- it really depends on your roof configuration, but the usual way is to cool the attic (e.g. with a fan) to freeze the water, then melt the ice dam from the outside. If you are lucky and get a warm day, the roof will dry by itself. Then just keep the snow off the roof for the rest of the season. Once the emergency is over, you have two options:

1. get your attic insulated and ventilated properly so that the roof remains frozen throughout the winter or
2. remove all snow from your roof as soon as it falls.

Comment: Attic ventilation is important also.  We only had gable end vents and had icicles all the time.  Added ridge vent with new roof and no more icicles.

Comment: @crip659 True. I added that.

Comment: @crip659 do you have soffit vents too?

Comment: @FreshCodemonger  Always had the soffit vents.  I imagine the ridge vent increased air flow over the two small gable vents or maybe the changed in direction from N-S to more W-E.  The soffits are W-E

Comment: @crip659 I did the same except I sealed my gable vents.  The airflow ideally should be from the soffit flowing up the underside of the roof sheathing to cool the shingles in the summer, the gable vents short circuit that airflow path.